# Global variable not accessible in function - jQuery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a global variable `creditAmount` that is populated via an ajax call when a user logs in. I would like to use that variable later on in another function that is called after login. How do I keep the value of `creditAmount` available for this later function?

This is where`creditAmount` gets defined and populated:

```
var creditAmount = "";

function getCustomer() {
  $(function() {
      $("#anId").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        var custEmail = $("anotherId").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "/return_customer",
          data: {email: custEmail},
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          complete: function(data) {
            creditAmount = data.responseJSON;
            form.submit();
          },
      });
  });
 });  
}
```

And then this is where I need to use `creditAmount`:

```
function getPendingCredit(){
  var modal = $("#fresh-credit-iframe");
  modal.load(function(){
      $(this).contents().find("#fresh-credit-continue-shopping").click(function(data){
      var enteredAmount = +($(modal).contents().find("#pending_credit_amount").val());
      console.log(creditAmount);
      $("#fresh-credit").hide();
  });
 });
}
```

Finally, this is how I call both functions, but by the time I get to here `creditAmount` is blank again

```
getCustomer();

if(creditAmount != ""){
  showModal(closeModal);
  getPendingCredit(creditAmount);
}
```

Comment: set a delay or use promises/callback.

Comment: What happens on form submit?

Answer (score 0):

set a delay or use promises/callback. There is a little time gap between the request which is sent with ajax and the response that is received to populate the variable.

Comment: No, I don't think thats it.. I set the variable with that ajax call and I have it, but then I submit the form and it looks like I lose the value I set in that variable.. not sure why